# JObject me tira un error cuando trato de obtener el resultado de un JSON

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, restful

Estoy llamando un Rest API. Al llamarlo se me cae y me da el siguiente error

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not
>   an object: StartArray`en la linea`JObject.Parse(resultWebService.ToString());

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saben como debo arreglarlo?

```
   IList<Parameters> searchResultsFromJason = new List<Parameters>();

    string resultJSonRequest = "";

    using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = reader.ReadToEnd();

        string resultWebService = Convert.ToString(result);

        JObject JasonResultList = JObject.Parse(resultWebService.ToString());

        resultJSonRequest = resultWebService;

        IList<JToken> results = JasonResultList["data"].ToList();

        IList<Parameters> searchResults = new List<Parameters>();

        searchResultsFromJason = searchResults;

        foreach (JToken resultJAson in results)
        {
            Parameters searchResult = resultJAson.ToObject<Parameters>();
            searchResults.Add(searchResult);

        }
    }
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Por favor, [edit] la pregunta y coloque el JSON que está procesando con este código.

Comment: puedes añadir un watcher de la linea que esta fallando ?

Comment: @Mike, listo acabo de editar la pregunta añadiendo el warcher. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personalmente uso JToken, considero que me da mas flexibilidad al momento de acceder a propiedades dinámicas. Usando el converter de NewtonSoft (que creo es el nuevo JSON.NET) puedes usar lo siguiente

```
IList<Parameters> searchResultsFromJason = new List<Parameters>();
string resultJSonRequest = "";
using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
using (var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    string resultWebService = Convert.ToString(result);        

    /*La opción sencilla es convertir a JToken*/        
    var JasonResultList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(resultWebService.ToString());

    resultJSonRequest = resultWebService;
    IList<JToken> results = SelectToken("data").ToObject<List<JToken>>();
    IList<Parameters> searchResults = new List<Parameters>();
    searchResultsFromJason = searchResults;
    foreach (JToken resultJAson in results)
    {
        Parameters searchResult = resultJAson.ToObject<Parameters>();
        searchResults.Add(searchResult);
    }
}
```

De pronto  te sirve hacer el casteo directamente gracias a las bondades de JToken:

```
IList<Parameters> searchResultsFromJason = new List<Parameters>();
string resultJSonRequest = "";
using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
using (var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    string resultWebService = Convert.ToString(result);        

    /*La opción sencilla es convertir a JToken*/        
    var JasonResultList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(resultWebService.ToString());

    resultJSonRequest = resultWebService;
    IList<JToken> searchResults = SelectToken("data").ToObject<List<Parameters>>();
    searchResultsFromJason = searchResults;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me resulto perfectamente!

Answer (score -1):

Deserealiza tu variable `resultWebService` en un modelo:

```
clas Modelo
{
 public string variable { get; set; }
}
Modelo info = new Modelo();

result = reader.ReadToEnd();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(result);
string data = Convert.ToString(obj);
info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Modelo>(data);
```

Al igual pueder recorrer esa colección llamada *info* con un `foreach`.